# How to get GroupID in Golang Kafka 10?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I am using Kafka 10.0 and https://github.com/Shopify/sarama.
I am trying to get the offset of the latest message that a consumer processed.

To do so I've found the method [NewOffsetManagerFromClient(group string, client Client)](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#NewOffsetManagerFromClient) which require the group name.

**How do I get consumer group name?**

```
offsets := make(map[int32]int64)

config := sarama.NewConfig()
config.Consumer.Offsets.CommitInterval = 200 * time.Millisecond
config.Version = sarama.V0_10_0_0

// config.Consumer.Offsets.Initial = sarama.OffsetNewest
cli, _ := sarama.NewClient(kafkaHost, config)
defer cli.Close()

offsetManager, _ := sarama.NewOffsetManagerFromClient(group, cli)
for _, partition := range partitions {
    partitionOffsetManager, _ := offsetManager.ManagePartition(topic, partition)
    offset, _ := partitionOffsetManager.NextOffset()

    offsets[partition] = offset
}
return offsets
```

I created a consumer with

```
consumer := sarama.NewConsumer(connections, config)
```

but I do not know how to create a consumer group and get its group name.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create your own offset manager to find current offsets:

```
offsetManager, _ := sarama.NewOffsetManagerFromClient(group, cli)
```

Similarly, the consumer that was consuming your topic's messages would have to use the same offset manager and they would have used a specific group id. Use that group id.

Comment: So I need to create a consumer group and give it a specific name of my choice, correct? Can that be done in using Shopify/sarama?

Comment: There are several ways to create a consumer. Using [NewConsumerFromClient](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#NewConsumerFromClient) allows you to set your offsets in the client prior to creating the consumer. To find the offsets you'd use the same group id so as to use the offset manager mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use any string as groupId. Please look at the example from [sarama GoDoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama)

```
// Start a new consumer group
group, err := NewConsumerGroupFromClient("my-group", client)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer func() { _ = group.Close() }()
```

Maybe you can give it any string. And you should make sure the other consumers can get the same groupId for joining the group.